# Error while passing arraylist as argument to INSERT data into Ignite cache using pyodbc

Tags: odbc, pyodbc, ignite

I have written following code to insert data into Ingite cache from python using ODBC driver. In this want to pass arraylist of strings(id_list) as argument. 
My list contains variable number of elements that is why I need to pass it as argument to query.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
select_string= "INSERT INTO Person (_key, id,  firstName, lastName, salary) VALUES (322, ? , 'abcd', 'dhsagd', 1000)"

id_list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
cursor.execute(select_string, id_list)
```

But when I pass list of strings as parameter to query I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonOdbclist.py", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.execute(select_string, id_list)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 4 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation, parameters should be passed as individual values or a tuple: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executesql-parameters. Are you trying to do an `executemany` to insert four rows in this example?

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#executemanysql-paras

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
select_string= "INSERT INTO Person (_key, id,  firstName, lastName, salary) VALUES (322, ? , 'abcd', 'dhsagd', 1000)"

id_list = [('test1',), ('test2',), ('test3',), ('test4',)]
cursor.executemany(select_string, id_list)
```

Comment: Hi, link you have mentioned specifies to execute SQL query over given list by taking elements within list one by one. Where as in my case I want to insert whole list in **id** column.

Comment: With above modifications you have mentioned I am again getting following error,                                                                         
  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pythonOdbclist_new.py", line 13, in <module>
    cursor.executemany(select_string, id_list)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 1 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
`

Comment: Hi @FlipperPA,I want to insert whole list in one row only. Thanks.

Comment: I think pyodbc is unable to recognise parameter marker **'?'** even though I specify it.